# Enable third party cookie in all browsers

Tags: javascript, jquery

I found a p3p header code for enabling third party cookies in safari, firefox, chrome, opera and all versions of IE. Thecode i found is
'P3P:CP=”IDC DSP COR ADM DEVi TAIi PSA PSD IVAi IVDi CONi HIS OUR IND CNT”'

But this code does not work in safari. Can any one suggest me some solution to enable the third party cookie?

Comment: I hope that you know what [all those tokens mean](http://www.p3pwriter.com/lrn_111.asp) and that you are using them truthfully.

Answer (score 6):

Safari disables all 3rd party cookies by default. There is no header you can set to enable it. This is a proper security measure and ideally should be adopted by all browsers.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. How can i find that Safari disables all 3rd party cookies by default?

Comment: Is there any way to enable third party cookie in safari by using javascript or jquery?

Comment: @Musakkhir No, of course not. That would entirely obviate the purpose of turning them off. It's a security measure meant to protect the user.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one: `CP="CAO PSA OUR"`

It is called the "compact version" as far as I remember.

Cheers.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But this code was also not working in safari. Please suggest me some solution.